# Parallel write to a memory mapped file

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, memory-mapped-files

I have a very large file memory mapped in C++ using Boost.

I need to update scattered parts of the file with new data. It takes a long time to prepare the data, so I am using multiple threads. Each thread prepares some data and then writes it to the memory mapped file. Each thread writes to a distinct area in the file.

The data in the file are being mangled.

If I was using multiple threads to write text out to an ordinary text file I would expect the output to be mangled. However I didn't expect that to happen in a memory mapped file (I guess I thought that because it looks like I am simply writing to individual array elements, not writing to a file where there is buffering).

Is it impossible to do parallel writes to a memory mapped file, even when the individual threads are accessing distinct array elements? Do I need to use a mutex?

Update #1
I create the mapped region as follows:

```
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
bip::file_mapping mapping(data_info.datafile.c_str(), bip::read_write);
bip::mapped_region mapped_region(mapping, bip::read_write);
unsigned char const* const mem_mapped_data = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mapped_region.get_address());
unsigned char *ptr = const_cast<unsigned char*>(mem_mapped_data);
```

I then pass the pointer (*ptr) to each thread which updates the data.

For example, thread 'A' might update 2 bytes at a given address, and thread 'B' might update the very next two bytes. In other words the threads can write to addresses very close to each other, but they always write to distinct addresses with no overlap.

Comment: Is the data you write to the file the ***exact*** same length as the old data you overwrite in the file? Otherwise, you will overwrite unrelated data if the new data is longer than the old, or leave old data if the new data is shorter. That the file is memory-mapped or not doesn't matter for this.

Comment: Parallel writes to a mmaped file are in principle OK. Your bug must be elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the old and new data are the exact same size.

Comment: Are you using file io to do the IO or are you using the file backed memory buffers? If I've given each thread, say, one k and they all have a buffer of like ... offset, offset + 1024 ..., it should be safe for each one to operate on the range of memory without needing to coordinate.

Comment: @Charlie I am not sure what you mean by this. I have updated the original question showing how I map the region and use it.

Comment: @John It's possible that, assuming your comments about byte proximity are correct, if you're not being careful about how you do the writes, you could get some weird failures due to writes in different threads hitting the same cache line. Ex: 2 threads read the same 64 bytes from ram, update their 2 bytes, and the flush the whole line (notably, without the changes done by the other thread). Try making the unit of ownership a multiple of 64 bytes (and 64 byte aligned).